# pass a string in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a function which require to pass some ids as comma seperated to the url string.

My code:

```
def shipment(self, orderItemIds):
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/shipments"
    payload = {'orderItemsIds':orderItemIds}
    return self.session.get(url, data=payload)
```

I need to pass id1, id2, id3 so that i get a link as:

```
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/shipments?orderItemsIds={id1,id2...}
```

I tried to pass it as a string. and as a list too. But it didn't worked.

```
oid = 'id1,id2,id3'                     # or
oid = ['id1',id2'','id3']
```

How to do it?

I passed an id as `oiids = '230501592'`.
On running response.url, it gives me:

```
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/shipments?orderItemsIds
```

It shows that parameter values are not passing in the url string.

Comment: Are you sure you need to have the multiple items in the *literal syntax* you posted? So `{` followed by `id1`, then a comma, etc.?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, even [the API docs](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIRef.html#get-orders-shipments-orderitemsids-id-list) are a bit unclear, but it's just `id1,id2,...`.

Comment: Ah, Flipkart again. They really need to work on their API documentation..

Comment: Yes @MartijnPieters I have to pass atleast 1 param. multiple values can help me parse a list of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is this (where `orderItemIds` is a list of strings):

```
def shipment(self, orderItemIds):
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/shipments"
    params = {'orderItemsIds': ','.join(orderItemIds)}
    return self.session.get(url, params=params)
```

The differences from the version you have in the question are that `orderItemIds` is assumed to be a list of strings and is being joined with commas, and the data keyword is replaced with params, which is the right choice for a GET request.

Comment: It gives `%2C` in url instead of `,`

Comment: `%2C` is the escape code for `,`; that's automatically done for compatibility reasons, but they're equivalent. See here for further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049152/passing-parameters-without-escaping-in-python3-requests

Comment: A bit more explanation would be helpful; you changed `data` to `params` (so that URL query parameters are generated instead of a request body) and joined the ids with commas.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily send get parameters in python requests library-

```
data = {
    'orderItemsIds': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
}

response = requests.get(url, data = data)
```

Comment: `data` is not the right keyword, and passing it a list will result in multiple instances of `orderItemsIds` in the URL, not one with a comma-separated list of ids.

Comment: You want to use `params`, not `data`. The former gives you URL parameters, the latter the request *body* (use that when POSTing instead).

Comment: But passing in the elements as a list will not produce the desired URL *anyway*. The question isn't clear if the OP can accept `orderItemsIds=id1&orderItemsIds=id2&orderItemsIds=id3` or that they really must have `orderItemsIds={id1,id2,id3}`.